# How do I convert Strings of an ArrayClass into Objects?

Tags: java

I'm trying to construct a for-each loop that converts individual `String`s of an `ArrayList` to objects of the `Product` class, so I may add them to an  Array.

```
public Order(String fileName, String order_id) {
    orderID = order_id + " JM";
    file = new FileReader(fileName);
    file.getLines();
    ArrayList<String> lineList = file.getLines();
    product_list = new ArrayList<Product>();

    //for each loop, insert the loop, create anonymous 
    //product type of objects, then add object here
    //product list.add.file[n]
    for ( String file : lineList){
        //Class c2 = Class.forName(cn);
        product_list.add(c1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to tell us what a `Product` is (i.e. its definition) and how a `String` should map to a `Product`.

Comment: Well, you somehow have to parse that string. I can't provide more details because I neither know what the strings would contain nor do I know what `Product` looks like.

Comment: In Java is no eval() method like in Javascript

Comment: Why are you calling `file.getLines()` twice? And if `FileReader` is Java’s standard `FileReader`, there is no `getLines()` method. And if it is not the standard `FileReader`, you should not give it the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Product class is like below:

```
class Product{
    private String name;
    //Constructor
    public Product(String name) {
         this.name=name;
    }
}
```

then,
your code shall look like

```
   for ( String file : lineList){ //you have selected strange name for file line. should be product name
        Product p = new Product(file);     
        product_list.add(p);
   }
```